# Data extract from MongoDB to PowerBi

Tags: r, mongodb, powerbi

I have been collecting data and storing them into MongoDB database but now i would like to extract/use these data into Power Bi. Because of the cost control i can't use the ODBC connector in the process but R scripts instead. Anyone can help with tips and hints on how to start ?

I am expecting the data to be in a table view where there are multiple columns which will enable the production of some KPI reports.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [R driver](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/).
However, if you just need to visualize some data, why not simply use [MongoDB Charts](https://www.mongodb.com/products/charts) - that would be the easiest way.